# How to check when radio 1 radio button is checked and the second radio button is also checked it does one thing but if not it does another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 radio buttons, 1 textarea and 1 number area (type = "number" input don't really know what to call it).

```
    if(mysql_num_rows($canview) > 0) { ?>

      <!-- Questions on return send all this to database then to place where dept. heads can see it-->
            <div id = "returnform" >
            <form action="" method="post">
                <h4>Are any of the item(s) missing?</h4>
                    Yes<input type ="radio" name ="missing" id = "missing1" value = "Yes" required>
                    No<input type ="radio" name ="missing" id = "missing2" value = "No" >
                    <div class = "lossnum">
                    <input type="number" name="lossnum" id = "lossnum" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                <h4>Was every item put back/plugged in correctly?</h4>
                    Yes<input type ="radio" name ="putback" id = "putback1" value = "Yes" required>
                    No<input type ="radio" name ="putback" id = "putback2" value = "No">
                <div class = "returncomments">  
                <h4>what happened?</h4>
                <textarea name="comments"></textarea> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item->get_id(); ?>" />
        <h4>Are you sure you want to return these <?php echo $item->get_name(); ?>? </h4>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Return" />
     <?php
}elseif(mysql_num_rows($canview) == 0 && $success == false) { ?>
    <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item->get_id(); ?>" />
```

I have already gotten the lossnum (number counter) to work right where it goes off and on, what I need is to make it so that the textarea only shows up when either radio button 1 equals yes or radio button 2 equals no or both are happening, right now if you click on radio button 1 as yes it shows up but if you then change it to no it does not go away so I need to change that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".lossnum").hide();
$(".comments").hide();
$(".returncomments").hide();
$(".commentup").hide();
$("#missing1").click(function () {
    $(".lossnum").show();
    $(".comments").show();
    $(".returncomments").show();

});
$("#missing2").click(function () {
    $(".lossnum").hide();
    if($('#putback2').prop('checked', value)){
        $(".comments").show();
        $(".returncomments").show();
    }
    else{
        $(".comments").hide();
        $(".returncomments").hide();


    }
    });
     $("#putback2").click(function () {
            $(".comments").show();
            $(".returncomments").show();
    });
    $("#putback1").click(function () {      
        if($('#missing2').prop('checked', value)){
            $(".comments").hide();
            $(".returncomments").hide();
        }
        else{
            $(".comments").show();
            $(".returncomments").show();
        }
    }); });
```

also if you guys know anyway to make it so it is required or checked on submit only when certain radio buttons are chosen (i.e. when putback is no you have to fill out textarea and/or when missing is yes you have to do the same)

heres a JSfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/SameB/L7et15du/

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your `if` condition in click handler of radio button. You are setting radio button value using `$('#putback2').prop('checked', value)` but you need to check if it is checked or not, see below code

```
$("#missing2").click(function () {
    $(".lossnum").hide();
    if($('#putback2').is(':checked')){//correct here
        $(".comments").show();
        $(".returncomments").show();
    }
    else{
        $(".comments").hide();
        $(".returncomments").hide();
    }
});
```

And same need to do for putback1

```
$("#putback1").click(function () {      
    if($('#missing2').is(':checked')){
        $(".comments").hide();
        $(".returncomments").hide();
    }
    else{
        $(".comments").show();
        $(".returncomments").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: jk ignore that if you saw it

Comment: ok changed that it still works hasn't fixed my problem but yeah good start i guess?

Comment: can you reproduce your problem on jsfiddle so that I can help you better

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/L7et15du/3/), you forgot to close `returncomments` div i.e. </div> and you have not used `is(':checked')` as per my posted  answer. Also you need not to use ` $(".comments").show();`

Comment: oh did see the :checked part hahaha i go do that and returncomments is closed i just didnt add it in by accident on the actual page it is though